# Choosing Past Simple or Past Perfect: Do I need "had" here?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Do I need "had" here? If yes, do I need to change "did" to "done"?

> A: Lucy accidentally broke her mum’s favorite cup yesterday.
>
> B:  Oh! I think her mom was really angry at her, right?
>
> A:  Not really.
>
> B:  Why not?
>
> A:  Well, as soon as she broke the cup she began to clean in the house. By the time her mom came back from work Lucy ***had*** cleaned three
>   rooms, ***did*** all the dishes in the kitchen, and even mopped the
>   staircase! Her mom was very happy when she got home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need *did* to change to perfect tense, to be consistent. Whether you want *done* or *had done* is a matter of preference:

> Lucy had cleaned three rooms, done all the dishes in the kitchen, and even mopped the staircase.
>
> Lucy had cleaned three rooms, had done all the dishes in the kitchen, and had even mopped the staircase.

The first version would be preferable since it makes just as much sense while being more concise.

Answer (score 1):

How about simplifying it to:

Lucy had cleaned three rooms, **washed** all the dishes in the kitchen, and even mopped the staircase! Her mom was very happy when she got home.

Comment: In some dialects (including where I'm from), it is more normal to say [do the dishes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do_the_dishes) than *wash the dishes*. (Especially in British English, [wash up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wash_up) may also be the normal way to say this.) So there's nothing wrong with wanting to use the past participle *done the dishes* rather than switch to a different verb :)